# graph polar coordinates $ r=4\sin(3\theta) $

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

Graph polar coordinates $ r=4\sin(3\theta) $

I was told by my teacher to split the graph into $3$ parts per quadrant and try those angles the problem arises when I plug $\dfrac{5\pi}{6}$ into the equation and I don't know what to do to solve it without a calculator. If someone has a better process to graphing polar equations/curves I would be grateful.

Comment: how is it the same as $ \frac {\pi}{2}? $ All I get it 5pi/2. I want to know how to calculate that without a calculator.

Comment: so is this saying that the 4pi/2 becomes 2pi which becomes zero and really all that's left is pi/2 which is 1? or is it just the rotations 5pi/2 is 5 rotations which still relates to the pi/2 which just makes sin 1?

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to answer your question in a more-general context- that way, you'll hopefully be able to sketch any (reasonable) polar curve.

Some useful points:

- Tangents at the pole: these occur when $r=0$ (when the curve is at the origin).

  In this case, tangents at the pole will be the values of $\theta$ satisfying $4\sin(3\theta)=0$ (which I'll leave you to solve).
- Maxima- these are points which are furthest from the origin- maxima occur when $\frac{dr}{d\theta}=0$ (and $\frac{d^2r}{d\theta^2}<0$).

In this case, the maxima are (some) solutions to $12\cos(3\theta)=0$ (which, again, I'll leave you to solve).

- Symmetry- for what value $\phi$ is $r$ periodic? i.e. for what $\phi$ is $r(\theta+\phi) \equiv r(\theta)$?

I'll give you this one for your question- the period is $\frac{2\pi}{\color{green}{3}}$.

That means you can split the graph into $\color{green}{3}$ parts, each of which will be (rotationally) symmetric to the others- one third of the work!

Once you've found and plotted maxima and tangents at the pole, it is now simply a matter of connecting the dots.

The final result is this:
[image]

What I've left out are the values of $\theta$ for which $r$ is maximum (in blue), and the values of $\theta$ for which $r$ is minimum (red). Try and do this yourself!

Comment: would the maxima also be where the tangent line equals zero?

Comment: The maxima occur when $\frac{dr}{d\theta}=0$ and when $\frac{d^2r}{d\theta^2}<0.$

Comment: I'm confused as to what tangents at the pole means? does it always mean when the function returns to the origin? or to zero?

Comment: The origin is (where $r=$) 0.

Comment: thank you, I'm behind in my studies and really lost.